# 100Base FX and 1000Base LX - are they compatible?

Tags: fiber

I have connected a D-Link DMC-515SC media converter with a 100Base FX port to a Cisco switch with a 1000Base LX port via a single mode patch lead but having issues. Tried swapping cores but not successful. Are they compatible?

Answer (score 2):

> 100Base FX and 1000Base LX - are they compatible?

No, not normally.

While both use ~1300 nm light, 100BASE-FX is designed for multi-mode fiber and 1000BASE-LX for single-mode. Very few 1000BASE-LX transceivers are downward compatible with 100BASE-FX, that's the prerequisite.

Depending on the exact transceiver types, one of the fiber types *might* work in between - if SMF doesn't, try MMF (reach may be rather poor). Also, the SFP port may require explicit configuration to 100M (`interface x speed 100`). After all, you might need a 100BASE-FX SFP module for the switch, or a Gigabit media converter.